# PHP json_decode \u0441 returns unexpected value

Tags: php, json, unicode

We are pulling some data from an api using PHP. It returns a JSON string which contains a variety of languages and their unicode encoded characters.

For example, one character returned in unicode is a 'c' - this is represented in the `JSON` string by the value `\u0441`

If I run json_decode on this string I get a `'Ñ'` which is clearly unexpected.

Is there a step i'm missing such as encoding conversion or is the raw api output incorrect?

Comment: Most likely you're simply not handling encodings correctly. \u0441 is decoded to a UTF-8 encoded "c" just fine, you're just not interpreting the result as UTF-8.

Comment: U+0441 encoded in UTF-8 is 0xD181, which when interpreted in a single-byte encoding like ISO 8895-1 is shown as two characters, `Ñ` (0xD1) and the control character 0x81 (non-printable). Fix the declaration of your output encoding and it should be alright.